# How to change PhpStorm theme bin/console background color / font color on error

Tags: phpstorm

The text is very hard to see in a dark console.

How can I change those colors?

[image]

I'm using PhpStorm Darcula Theme

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to modify the theme e.g

Open

> Preferences -> Editor -> Colors Scheme -> Console Colors

Then press `Save As` button and give theme copy name and change the desired color, as given below

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Change gray color in 'Console colors' to F1DDDD, to get same effect as on the image.

UPDATE: now color name is White(Gray) instead of Gray.

[image]